# Polymer with Angular5 and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, polymer

We are thinking on starting two projects, one with Angular 5 and another one with Polymer. The second is destinated to be a component library to reuse in the Angular 5 project and also in other AngularJS projects.

I've been searching on how to integrate Angular and Polymer and it seems easy. If I'm not wrong, we can generate a build with polymer and then load that js in our index to use the components (correct me if I'm wrong).

Te problem comes with AngularJS project. I guess we can use the polymer component library the same way that we use it in Angular 5 but I'm not sure and I have not found any clear articles on the Internet. Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that you can use polymer components into frameworks like AngularJS, but it is not that easy to fill in the gaps.

There are lots of components like `vaadin/angular-polymer` , `codebakery/origami` but they have their own limitations.

Check this following page from Jorge Antonio Gómez Colombat

[integrating-polymer-3-components-on-angular-5](https://medium.com/@tonytunes2005/integrating-polymer-3-components-on-angular-5-317f8c43ef03)